# Wind quintet or sextet minus one

Tags: woodwinds, ensemble

This question arose from a situation where our group of amateur but experienced players was to meet to play through [Janáček's Mládí](https://imslp.org/wiki/Ml%C3%A1d%C3%AD_%28Jan%C3%A1%C4%8Dek,_Leo%C5%A1%29) and the [Lefebvre Suite for Winds](https://imslp.org/wiki/Suite_for_Winds_No.2,_Op.122_%28Lefebvre,_Charles%25). The Janáček is scored for

```
Flute/Piccolo
Oboe
Clarinet
Bass clarinet
Horn
Bassoon
```

while the Lefebvre is scored for

```
Flute
Oboe 
2 clarinets
Horn
Bassoon.
```

Unfortunately (scenario 1) the flautist was unable to attend owing to a family emergency and the play-through had to be cancelled because there was no music available for the remaining musicians to play as an ensemble.

Similar situations (scenario 2) have occurred in the past where we have planned to meet as a standard wind quintet (flute, oboe, clarinet, horn and bassoon) but one person has had to drop out at short notice.

As far as I know there is no repertoire for the remaining instruments of scenario 1 above (oboe, two clarinets with one possibly doubling bass clarinet, horn and bassoon). The situation with the quintet missing a player (scenario 2) is a little easier because there are some pieces for oboe, clarinet, horn and bassoon and many more for standard woodwind quartet of flute, oboe, clarinet and bassoon. Unfortunately these latter pieces do not lend themselves easily to adaptation for oboe, clarinet, horn and bassoon because the flute parts are too high to be played on the oboe. The clarinet might well be able to play the oboe part if transposed but the horn would struggle to play the clarinet part.

Of course there is nothing to say that the flute is always going to be the missing instrument - this is just by way of example. So my questions are:

(1) Can anyone suggest anything in the repertoire that would have allowed a play-through to go ahead in either of the two scenarios above?

(2) More generally, is there any way (when thinking about a wind group) of making arrangements properly flexible? There are so-called flexible arrangements out there, but they tend to be addressed more towards beginners - perhaps inevitably, because if parts are to be playable on almost all instruments they have to made simple.

My investigations so far have led me towards something like the Albrechtsberger Serenata a 5 as being a possible answer to the first scenario (because the flute part is also playable on the oboe and the oboe part if transposed would be playable on a clarinet):

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. I suppose you're generally more likely to find that earlier music is more flexible. Renaissance music often lacks instrumental designations entirely and rarely depends on the unique capability of any instrument. This will be a more practical option if the clarinetists and horn can transpose at sight, since you're more likely to find parts at concert pitch than transcribed for modern wind ensemble. Much baroque and classical music will be playable by any instrument of the appropriate range, but there won't be much chamber music for horn, so idiomatic parts will be lacking.

Comment: I had the same thought as phoog, as well as another that might not be what you're looking for: explore improvisation! It sounds like this group really enjoys getting together to sight-read (or play after prep) wind repertoire of the Common Practice period. For that, and especially with this instrumentation, there's not a lot to do when you're missing a member and others don't overlap in register or have very different instrumental abilities. But the group could do a lot with, maybe not totally free improvisation, but inventing your own "variations on a theme"-type activity.

Comment: While this is very interesting, it seems to be essentially an identification question.

Comment: Another possibility is to get a C clarinet (they're uncommon but do exist) and play down an octave if needed.  That way the clarinet player can cover for either flute or oboe.

Comment: I agree with @ToddWilcox, but the post could easily be reframed as solely a composition/arranging by focusing on "what considerations are involved in making flexible scores?" That seems like a valuable question. The Albrechtsberger could certainly be included as an example.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions. I shall give some thought to posting a more general question as suggested by @Aaron.

Comment: @Duston  or an Eb soprano clarinet, assuming the player can (as we all should) transpose from concert pitch.    Or go way out there and have a violin cover the flute part.  Goodness knows I've been in trios and quartets that went the other way (a flute covering one of the violin parts)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Eb soprano clarinets make nifty lamps, but I don't know that I'd want one in my quintet.  But my point is the real benefit of the C clarinet is that you don't have to transpose at all.

Comment: @Duston  agreed -- but save that Eb -- it's needed for some polkas and a few Mahler symphonies :-)